# How to dynamically query a mongoDB document

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and I'm not sure if I phrased my question right, but here are the details:

I'm using PyMongo and I have a document like so:

```
{'_id': 1, 
 'user_ratings': [
      {'Bob': 3},
      {'Jane': 4}
  ] 
}
```

My initial operation was to set `'Bob'` to a new number, say 5. The correct way to do this was this:

```
db.ratings.update_one({'_id': 1, 'user_ratings.Bob': 3}, {'$set': {"user_ratings.$.Bob": 5} })
```

This works as expected, but within the above query, I would like to make it so that it doesn't matter what `user_ratings.Bob` is set to. If I omit this match, PyMongo will complain that the positional operator didn't find the match needed for the query.

Is there any way to sort of put a placeholder that would mean any value? Or if such doesn't exist, would there be a kind of workaround to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying, that PyMongo complains when you omit `'user_ratings.Bob': 3`?

Comment: @Tim-Erwin Yes, that's correct. Because MongoDB docs specifically mention *array field **must** appear as part of the query document*

Comment: Could you dynamically query for the document you want to change, keep it in a variable and then supply it again?

Comment: @pdowling I'm pretttty sure it's possible. That's probably the workaround I'm looking for though. Let me see if that's retrievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the schma of your objects to something like this:

```
{'_id': 1, 
 'user_ratings': [
      {'user': 'Bob', 'rating': 3},
      {'user': 'Jane': 'rating': 4}
  ] 
}
```

Now you can query like this:

```
db.ratings.update_one(
    {'_id': 1, 'user_ratings.user': 'Bob'},
    {'$set': {'user_ratings.$.rating': 5} })
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's actually a lot more sensible than the schema I had! And thanks for the answer :-)